# How do I enumerate this subclass without getting an Invalid Casting Exception error?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, ienumerable

I've been trying to look into making classTwo enumerable but I'm getting an error I don't quite understand as most of the resources I'm looking at have this section of code in them...

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return (IEnumerator)this;
}
```

But I'm getting an error on the return line. Here is the rest of my code...

```
class classOne {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float Z;

    public classOne() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    public classOne(float X, float Y, float Z) {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        z = Z;
    }
}
class classTwo {
    public classOne a;
    public classOne b;
    public classOne c;


    public classTwo() {
        a = new classOne();
        b = new classOne();
        c = new classOne();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return (IEnumerator)this; 
        //Error: InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx).

First,

```
return (IEnumerator)this;
```

`classTwo` doesn't implement `IEnumerator` so you can't cast it as an `IEnumerator`.

Also, if `classTwo` is meant to be enumerated then it should implement `IEnumerable`. You would define another class that implements `IEnumerator`, and then `GetEnumerator` would return an instance of that class.

Comment: I do not know how to "implement IEnumerator" so that it works with the class I've made. Do I really need an entire new class with everything you linked in the sample code in order to make my class usable in a `foreach`?

Comment: if its really only about using this class in a foreach loop, why not use arrays or collections?

Comment: In practice I haven't implemented this once since .NET 1.1. Once we had generic collections I've never needed it. I'm sure there are reasons to implement it. I either haven't encountered one or didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because `classTwo` is not an `IEnumerator`. You need to declare that it is (`class classTwo : IEnumerator`) and then implement the `IEnumerator` interface's methods (`Current`,`MoveNext()`, and `Reset()`):

```
class classTwo : IEnumerator {

    public object Current {get;}
    public bool MoveNext() { ... }
    public void Reset() { ... }

    ...

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() 
    {
        return this; 
    }
}
```

**If you just want to make it usable in a `foreach` statement**, then you can write an iterator by using  `yield` statements:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
     yield return a;
     yield return b;
     yield return c; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its not answering the Question of how to implement IEnumerable/IEnumerator, but since all the fields are of the same type (classOne), you could simply either use an Array or a Collection (List in specific) to "bundle" the references in a way you can plug them in your foreach loop (took that from one of your comments). classTwo, at least in your current form, would become redundant.

usuage example

```
//if you know how many elements it will be, use an array
ClassOne[] classOneArray = new ClassOne[3];
ClassOne[0] = new ClassOne(); //a
ClassOne[1] = new ClassOne(); //b
ClassOne[2] = new ClassOne(); //c
foreach(ClassOne element in classOneArray) {
    //do smthg
}

//if you dont know how many elements it will be, use a list
List<ClassOne> classOneList = new List<ClassOne>();
classOneList.Add(new ClassOne()); //a
classOneList.Add(new ClassOne()); //b
classOneList.Add(new ClassOne()); //c
foreach(ClassOne element in classOneList) {
    //do smthg
}
```

`List<T>` requires you to use System.Collections.Generic - there also are a whole bunch of other collections available to you, depending on how you need your data layed out.

Please just ignore the answer if you have a specific use case where you need to implement the interface yourself and refer to the other two answers.

Comment: sorry the actual class I want to use is a bit different I just dumbed it down and removed a lot of the fields to make the question easier to answer. the other two answers don't really give me enough information, I've no idea how to modify what they've given me to work with my class.